# How to make different pages using Javascript and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a (web) app for a school project, using Phonegap. I'm writing IT in Javascript, HTML and CSS, and I am very new to coding.

My question seems to me to be pretty straightforward, but I can't seem to find any solution on the internet.

I have finished my homepage, but now I need a button which directs you to another page (the menu), from where you can go to other pages within the app. But I just can't find out how to make different pages, and how to direct users to those pages.

Comment: Check out https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/pages-multi-page/ jQuery Mobile can help you make multi-page "sites", very useful in Phonegap.

Comment: StackOverflow is not really the best place for this kind of question. I'd suggest finding a good tutorial or workshop and working your way through it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are two ways I see you can do this. Either make a new program (new HTML file) and make the button redirect you to that or completely clear the page using `document.write("")` and rebuild it.